# Parsing JSON using Thermal API for Wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wordpress

Im using the [Thermal API](http://thermal-api.com/) to make my wordpress blog's posts available to another website I am currently developing locally. I am using the jQuery Ajax function to make the request and retrieve the content node, but the data is not coming through. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:'http://tubecrush.net/wp_api/v1/posts?callback=show',
                    dataType:"jsonp",
                    type:"get",
                    success:function(data){
                        $('#result').html(data.content);
                    }
                });
            });
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      </head>
  <body>
        <h1>Result:</h1>
        <div id="result">
            
        </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp)

> **JSONP**
>
> If the URL includes the string `"callback=?"` (or similar, as defined by
>   the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead.

Note, returned `data` object appear to have property name `posts` having array of objects as value. `content` property value `""` ; `content_display` property value appear to contain `html`.

See also [deferred.then()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/)

```js
$.getJSON("http://tubecrush.net/wp_api/v1/posts?callback=?")
.then(function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
  $.each(data.posts, function(key, html) {
    $("#result").append(html.content_display)
  });
  // return promise return value `data`
  // return data
}, function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<h1>Result:</h1>
        <div id="result">
            
        </div>
```